# How do I add checkbox column to ExtJS 5 grid?

Tags: extjs

I want to have a checkbox (true/false) for my extjs grid.
When I try to add item of xtype : 'checkbox' I get an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: column.isColumnHidden is not a function

I've seen on a a post that there is a plugin of checkbox column that needs to be downloaded and included in ExtJS , Isn't there a built in option in ExtJS 5 for checkbox in a grid ?

Comment: Found the correc xtype : checkcolumn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I use checkbox, I download extjs library from official site and build develompent version of if via extjs console.

My extjs grid with checkbox was look like this:

```
{
    xtype:'checkcolumn',
    fieldLabel: 'checkbox_label',
    name: 'checkbox_name',
    text: 'text'
}
```

So full grid code will look like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    frame: true,
    title: 'Users',
    collapsible: true,
    height: 250,
    bind: '{depGrid.selection.users}',
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            xtype:'checkcolumn',
            fieldLabel: 'checkbox_label',
            name: 'checkbox_name',
            text: 'text'
        }
    ]
}
```

Also you cat try to add to checkbox `dataIndex` field and set to it some boolean variable from your model. Good luck!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle because I keep getitng error : column.isColumnHidden is not a function when adding the exact code you wrote.

Comment: The correct xtype is checkcolumn , update your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: This solved my problem, very unfortunate sencha is incapable of providing error messages which are actually relevant